# Facebook Review and Submission

Tags: facebook

[image: submission review]

I have a problem with submission review, everything is okay, but it's only have one issue at **Item review**.
I try to use any user at "Roles" tab to login, but after logged in facebook app show: "app not setup this app is still in development". But, I was checked it. and it was changed to green status.
Hope you can help me ? 
Thanks so much.

Comment: More: https://gyazo.com/4a2ab71b2a63d6d468c70a9de6675f29

Comment: You can test a request as an admin, developer or tester even if your app is in development mode, so if you're on dev mode the message you mention won't even show. If you've set your app in public mode and are using permissions which are unapproved for your app (in this case, publish_actions) you will STILL be able to use them if admin, dev or tester of the app, but normal people won't. That's why you get that message. I would try and make the Graph API calls necessary to test the publish_actions permission and then submit for review, you should be OK.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm done yet.